# filtering the data by knowing the number of bills that were not done for each employee

Tags: c#

I want to filtering the data from dgv1 to dgv2 by knowing the number of bills that were not done for each employee separately, such as the picture:
[image]

Comment: your picture has some problems.

Comment: https://ibb.co/7WbtWV9 this is picher

Comment: No, I mean another thing, for Example: `sam` in dgv1 has 3 undone action; but in dgv2 has 4 undone action.

Comment: example mark in dgv1 have 2 row done and 2row not done Helna have 2 billing done and 3 not done i want to make order to get this type of filter

Answer (score 0):

can this code help you?

```cs
List<string> selsepersons = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv1.Rows)
    if (!selsepersons.Contains(row.Cells["selseperson"].Value.ToString()))
        selsepersons.Add(row.Cells["selseperson"].Value.ToString());
foreach (string name in selsepersons)
{
    int done = 0, undone = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv1.Rows)
        if (row.Cells["selseperson"].Value.ToString() == name)
        {
            done += row.Cells["actiontype"].Value.ToString() == "done" ? 1 : 0;
            undone += row.Cells["actiontype"].Value.ToString() == "not done" ? 1 : 0;
        }
    dgv2.Rows.Add(name, done, undone);
}
```

Comment: i want to get data from dgv1 from actiontype and salesperson the first row have emp name and the second have action done or not this code get an error

Comment: thank you its work but some error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @AhmedHamed because your datagridviews' columns' names are different. dgv1's column 1 name is `selseprson`, correct that to `selseperson`.